# Ruby RoR, Ransack, multiple select query fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ransack

using the ransack gem i've seen that it should be possible to use a form with multiple select.

using the basic html for the select form I use, and then select BOTH options to that I can attempt to search for either value

```
<select id="q_c_0_v_0_value" name="q[c][0][v][0][value][]" size="1" multiple="multiple">
<option value="SGD">SGD</option>
<option value="USD">USD</option>
</select>
```

and also tried

```
<select id="q_c_0_v_0_value" name="q[c][0][v][0][value]" size="1" multiple="multiple">
<option value="SGD">SGD</option>
<option value="USD">USD</option>
</select>
```

with combinations for all of the predicates "equal any", "contains any" etc,

I get resulting

```
SELECT "auctions".* FROM "my_table" WHERE (("auctions"."currency" LIKE '%["SGD", "USD"]%'))
```

and

```
 SELECT "auctions".* FROM "my_table" WHERE ("auctions"."currency" LIKE '%USD')
```

Any ideas, the link https://github.com/ernie/ransack/issues/7 says its possible, but I dont seem to get the right results.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Where you able to solve this issue?

Comment: This [http://stackoverflow.com/a/39271500/2768540](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39271500/2768540) may have the answer