# Is there a simple way to show associated models after Ransack searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, ransack

guys. I have two simple models:

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews

end
```

and

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :restaurant

end
```

Task is to show all reviews after restaurant or restaurants found

Something like that

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @search = Restaurant.search(params[:q])
  @reviews = @search.result.reviews
end
```

end

But this code does not know reviews message cause it`s not an AR::Relation

A very bad solution looks like

```
def index
  @search = Restaurant.ransack(params[:q])
  @reviews = @search.result.each_with_object([]) do |rest, arr|
     arr << rest.reviews
  end
```

end

But views are very awful. Is there a simple way to get reviews?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**How about this**

```
def index
  @search  = Restaurant.ransack(params[:q])
  @reviews = Review.where(restaurant_id: @search.result.pluck(:id))
end
```

Comment: It is very funny. I click submit button on reviews_path and it redirects me to restaurants_path and shows restaurants found

Answer (score 1):

Ransack's docs state you can preload off of the result. [See here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#in-your-controller).

Updated code would look something like this:

```
class RestaurantController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @q = Restaurant.ransack(params[:q])
    @restaurants = @q.result.includes(:reviews)
  end
end
```

Lastly, here's an interesting related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39271500/648695